# Formatting grouped elements with Hadoop’s map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have use case to write Map Reduce code for the below problem:

```
3 : the  
3 : and  
3 : you  
4 : then  
4 : what  
4 : when  
5 : steve  
5 : where  
8 : savannah  
8 : research
```

The below is the output I am trying to achieve , where I am facing problem writing a reducer to group text elements
    They get grouped as:

```
3 : [the, and, you]  
4 : [then, what, when]  
5 : [steve, where]  
8 : [savannah, research]
```

Comment: The reducer already gets the data in the output format you have mentioned. Key and the list of values. What's the problem you are getting here ? Please try to bring it to a point which can be worked upon easily. The problem statement looks abstract.

Comment: Actuallu i am stick with the reducer method where i am trying to group. But it is failing.